# Mockito when then not working a Injected Mock in a concrete method in a abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a class that extends an abstract class. The concrete class members are Injected and when a method from the concrete class Mockito *when-then* returns null for the method call even though I have defined it in the test.

Abstract Class

```java
public abstract class A {

    @Inject
    ObjA objA;

    public String methodA() {
       return objA.x()
    }
    // unimplemented methods
}
```

Class B

```java
public class B extends A {

    @Inject
    ObjB objB;

    public String methodB() {
       String x = methodA()
       return x;
    }
}
```

TestClass

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BTest{
    @Mock
    ObjA objA
    
    @Mock
    ObjB objB

    @InjectMock
    B b;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        Mockito.when(objA.x()).thenReturn("Hi");
    }

    @Test
    public testBMethod() {
        String x = b.methodB();
        assertEquals(x,"Hi") // X is null even when, when then is defined for mocked object
    }

}
```

Can someone let me know why the *when-then* didn't work?

Comment: You may use `ReflectionTestUtils` from spring framework to assign the mock in your class under test before your test.

Comment: methodB is clearly missing it's return statement...

Comment: The mocked class is injected into the base class. When I debug the test I do see ObjA as a MockitoInstance but the when then is not triggered for this mocked object

Comment: I do have a return in method B missed while posting the question

Comment: There's another important discrepancy: methodA calls x without parameters, you mock it with a String parameter...